# Is it possible to make the background of FullCalendar calendar events transparent?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm relatively new with web and I am using FullCalendar on a personal project and am trying to accomplish what I would think would be relatively easy. I may have to change some code around as I don't think what I want is available out of the box.

Here is a screenshot of my version of the FullCalendar I am using: 
[image]

As you can see, I have several "events", well essentially they're a group of events and instead you just see the number of events for that day. So for Today, there are 10 events essentially, I just group them up. The problem is, you have to click above the event in order for the cell to select. I am trying to make it so that the event or the count text IS essentially the background without the rectangle, etc. See the screenshot below for what I am going for:
[image]

Making the eventColor transparent just makes the entire event disappear which is not what I want. I've also tried changing the background and border colors. The rectanglular shape is still present. Any ideas or possible suggestions regarding this? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you mean, could you show us an example?

If you want the user to click "trhough" the event, you can use the CSS

```
pointer-events: none
```

This will ignore the mouse events (such as click) on this element, and then click on the one behind.

Comment: Perfect! That actually was exactly what I needed. I just made the background transparent and added in the pointer-events: none to my className and it works like a charm. Thanks again @Foloribon. Now I just need to remove the little bar that's to the left of the event itself.